# Will I hurt relations between user made villages in Millenaire NPC Mod?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-millenaire

I've created two villages in Minecraft's Millenaire Mod using the villager-purchased rod. One of these villages is Norman and the other is Japanese. These two villages are fairly close together.

If I then proceeded to take an army of hired Normans to wipe out a far off Japanese village, will I hurt relations between the Norman and Japanese villages I created, or will they be unaffected because I created them?

(Additional Information: The Japanese village I am attacking is located close to a Minecraft-generated NPC village. By wiping out the Japanese village, I will gain control of this area)

Comment: You could always make a backup of your world and try it out! :)

Comment: You might want to clean up your question a little, it's hard to understand what is being asked here.

Comment: You could always just avoid genocide by moving the vanilla village, if you're feeling peaceful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will be unaffected, you can change that if you would like with certain mod managers but they would also wipe out your progress.